# Define the type of singularity of $f(z)=\frac{z^2-sin(z^2)}{z^3}$ at $z=0$

Tags: complex-analysis

Define what kind of singularity the following function has on $z=0$: 
$$
f(z)=\begin{cases} 
\dfrac{z^{2} -\sin (z^{2} )}{z^{3}}, & z\ne 0 \\ 0,&z=0.\end{cases}
$$

Well, I understood how I can solve this question, actually by finding Taylor expansion of $z^2-\sin(z^2)$ and multiplying it by $\frac{1}{z^3}$, I can obviously see that we're dealing with a "zero of order 3".

My question is, why I can't say that after applying L'Hopital's rule to calculate the limit: $$\mathop{\lim }\limits_{z\to 0} \frac{z^{2} -\sin (z^{2} )}{z^{3} },  $$ which turns out to be zero after deriving 3 times the upper and lower function.

Note: I figured out its okay to use L'Hopitals rule on complex function as long as we're dealig with analytic functions.

This limit is finite, and the function is bounded close to $z=0$, because the limit is finite. so why is that contradicting with the definition of removable singularity at $z=0$ ?

Comment: Hint: Think again what the Taylor expansion of  $z^2-\sin(z^2)$ is.

Comment: I can see what u might be implying. if I write it, I get the following: $z^6(\frac{1}{3!} - \frac{1}{5!}z^4 ... )$, so its a zero of order 6. and the lower function is a zero of order 3, so finally, we get a zero of order 3. but still, reaching a finite limit which is zero doesn't contradict with removable singularity!

Comment: Please order your thoughts and clarify what exactly it is that you want to prove with the l'Hopital argument. Can you justify that l'Hopital is applicable to complex functions (in a way that does not involve Taylor expansions in the limit point)? Also elaborate on the contradiction or insufficiency for the removable singularity.

Comment: You will need finiteness in a neighborhood, not only in $z=0$. From the Taylor expansion this is trivial, however without any power series expansion, how will you argue?

Comment: so i think I got what has been confusing me. reaching a finite limit at $z=0$ is not enough to ensure that we have removable singularity. we can still have an analytic function with a zero of some order. in order to distinguish between the two cases we always need to see the power series expansions . am I rght  ?